# excluding values from search when finding n value in Java

Tags: java

I am trying to find n number of values from my Hash Map  and put them into different lists to assign to a different font size. I have the maximum and second maximum values in different lists but when I try 3rd or 4th or so on it adds words that have already been found with only the last word being different. There may be more than key (word) with the same value so sorting through and going by index isn't really an option. Can you help.

```
    //searching for biggest value
    for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> en : wordToCountMap.entrySet()) {
        if (max1 == null || en.getValue().compareTo(max1.getValue()) > 0) {
            max1 = en;
            largestList.clear();
            largestList.add(max1.getKey());
        }
    }
    //searching for second largest value
    for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> en : wordToCountMap.entrySet()) {
        if (en != max1 && (max2 == null || (en.getValue().compareTo(max2.getValue()) > 0))) {
            max2 = en;

            secondlargestList.add(max2.getKey());
        }
    }
    //searching for third largest value
    for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> en : wordToCountMap.entrySet()) {
        if (en != max1 && en != max2 && (max3 == null || (en.getValue().compareTo(max3.getValue()) > 0))) {
            max3 = en;

            thirdlargestList.add(max3.getKey());
        }
    }
```

which outputs
[season][mostly, going, much, seasons, one][mostly, going, much, seasons]

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do, and reading the code isn't helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It really takes some time to understand what you're trying to do.
I think you should first get the entries' values as a list - that you can sort easily.

```
List<Integer> values = wordToCountMap.values().stream.collect(Collectors.toList());
Collections.sort(values);
Collections.reverse(values);
```

Now the values are sorted high to low, and you can use that list.

```
Integer highestValue = values.get(0);
List<String> wordsWithHighestValue = wordToCountMap.entrySet().stream()
                           .filter(e -> e.getValue().equals(highestValue))
                           .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

However, I'd probably go with first creating lists of words with the same count.

```
NavigableMap<Integer,List<String>> countToWordsMap = new TreeMap<>(wordToCountMap.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Map.Entry::getValue,
                           Collectors.mapping(Map.Entry::getKey, Collectors.toList())));
```

Or the somewhat more readable

```
NavigableMap<Integer,List<String>> countToWordsMap = new TreeMap<>();
for (Map.Entry<String,Integer> entry : wordToCountMap.entrySet()) {
    Integer count = entry.getValue();
    List<String> list = countToWordsMap.computeIfAbsent(count, new ArrayList<String>());
    list.add(entry.getKey());
    countToWordsMap.put(count, list);
}
```

Comment: Sorry, with the <> in the new ArrayList<> in the last block of code, I get Cannot infer arguments

Answer (score 0):

You need to check:

```
en.getValue() != max2.getVaue();
```

because you can't compare objects:

```
en != max2;
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you are trying to retrieve a list of words with highest count. Here is some code. Hope it will help:

```
/**
 * This is only convenient facade, using in tests.
 *
 * @param wordMap
 * @param level
 * @return
 */
public List<String> getMaxList(Map<String, Integer> wordMap, int level) {
    return getMaxList(wordMap.entrySet(), level);
}

/**
 * Returns list of words with highest counts, from highest to lowest
 *
 * @param wordMapEntrySet
 * @param level indicates how many words with highest count you want.
 * @return
 */
private List<String> getMaxList(Set<Map.Entry<String, Integer>> wordMapEntrySet, int level) {

    //Convert set to list, because set is not sortable
    List<Map.Entry<String, Integer>> list = new ArrayList<>(wordMapEntrySet);

    //Sort the list
    list.sort((mapEntry1, mapEntry2) -> {
        //Comparing two entries - comparing values (which is actualy a word count)
        //Ordering from highest value to lowest
        //Changing compare to mapEntry1...compareTo(mapEntry2) will sort the list in reverse order, i.e. from lowest to highest
        return mapEntry2.getValue().compareTo(mapEntry1.getValue());
    });

    //Return a sublist of the sorted list
    //Need to return only the keys from the Map.Entry, because the word is the key.
    return list.subList(0, level).stream().map(stringIntegerEntry -> stringIntegerEntry.getKey()).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Here is a unit test for testing:

```
public class WordCountTest {

    WordCount wc = new WordCount();

    private Map<String, Integer> createMap() {
        Map<String, Integer> wordMap = new HashMap<>();
        wordMap.put("AA", 3);
        wordMap.put("AB", 30);
        wordMap.put("AC", 300);
        wordMap.put("AD", 3000);
        wordMap.put("AE", 30000);
        wordMap.put("AF", 1000);
        wordMap.put("AG", 100);
        wordMap.put("AH", 10);
        wordMap.put("AI", 1);
        return wordMap;
    }

    private Map<String, Integer> createMapSame() {
        Map<String, Integer> wordMap = new HashMap<>();
        wordMap.put("AA", 3);
        wordMap.put("AB", 30);
        wordMap.put("AC", 300);
        wordMap.put("AD", 3000);
        wordMap.put("AE", 30000);
        wordMap.put("AF", 30000);
        wordMap.put("AG", 3000);
        wordMap.put("AH", 300);
        wordMap.put("AI", 30);
        return wordMap;
    }


    @Test
    public void testMaxWordCount() {
        List<String> maxWordList = wc.getMaxList(createMap(),3);
        Assert.assertEquals(maxWordList.get(0), "AE");
        Assert.assertEquals(maxWordList.get(1), "AD");
        Assert.assertEquals(maxWordList.get(2), "AF");
    }


    @Test
    public void testMaxWordCountWithSameCount() {
        List<String> maxWordList = wc.getMaxList(createMapSame(), 4);
        Assert.assertEquals(maxWordList.get(0), "AE");
        Assert.assertEquals(maxWordList.get(1), "AF");
        Assert.assertEquals(maxWordList.get(2), "AD");
        Assert.assertEquals(maxWordList.get(3), "AG");
    }

}
```